# Electron Multiple Button Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm putting my webpage inside Electron and everything is going well except with some buttons on the page, only the first button correctly does its function of randomly picking something from a javascript array while the rest of the buttons don't work, but everything works in the browser. Is there additional functions I need to include in `index.js` to allow multiple javascript functions to run?

Here is the code:

**This is the HTML side (Working in Browser):**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>What Should I Draw</title>
    <style>
        .button {
            background-color: #008CBA;
            border:           none;
            color:            white;
            padding:          15px 32px;
            text-align:       center;
            text-decoration:  none;
            display:          inline-block;
            font-size:        16px;
            margin:           4px 2px;
            cursor:           pointer;
            top:              50%;
        }

        .wrapper {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .demo {
            text-align:     center;
            color:          #008CBA;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size:      300%;
        }

        .remo {
            text-align:     center;
            color:          #008CBA;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size:      300%;
        }

        .temo {
            text-align:     center;
            color:          #4CAF50;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size:      200%;
        }

        .zemo {
            text-align:     center;
            color:          #4CAF50;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size:      200%;

        }

        .kemo {
            text-align:     center;
            color:          #4CAF50;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size:      200%;

        }

        .uemo {
            text-align:     center;
            color:          #4CAF50;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size:      200%;

        }

        .buttons {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border:           none;
            color:            white;
            padding:          15px 32px;
            text-align:       center;
            text-decoration:  none;
            display:          inline-block;
            font-size:        16px;
            margin:           4px 2px;
            cursor:           pointer;
            top:              50%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <input id="btnSearch" class="button" type="button" value="Randomize Subject" onclick="getRandomArrayElements(3);"/>
    <input id="btnSearch" class="button" type="button" value="Randomize Restriction" onclick="GetValue();"/>
</div>
<p id="demo" class="demo"></p>
<p id="remo" class="remo"></p>


<script>
    function getRandomArrayElements (count) {
        var arr      = ['Swamp', 'Tank', 'Claws', 'Flying Tank'];
        var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
        while (i-- > min) {
            index           = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
            temp            = shuffled[index];
            shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
            shuffled[i]     = temp;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = shuffled.slice(min);
    }
</script>
<div>
    <script>
        function GetValue () {
            var myArray = new Array("Steampunk", "Horror", "Cartoon", "Anime", "Cheesy");
            var random  = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
            document.getElementById("remo").innerHTML = random;
        }
    </script>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Type of Landscape" onclick="Landscape();"/>
        <input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Man Made Element" onclick="Manmade();"/>
        <input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Time of Day" onclick="Timeofday();"/>
        <input id="btnSearch" class="buttons" type="button" value="Randomize Weather" onclick="Weather();"/>

        <p id="kemo" class="kemo"></p>
        <p id="uemo" class="uemo"></p>
        <p id="zemo" class="zemo"></p>
        <p id="temo" class="temo"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        function Weather () {
            var myArray = new Array("Clear Skies", "Clear Skies", "Clear Skies", "Clear Skies", "Clear Skies", "Partly Cloudy");
            var random  = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

            document.getElementById("temo").innerHTML = random;
        }
    </script>
    <div>
        <script>
            function Timeofday () {
                var myArray = new Array("Noon", "Morning", "Sunrise", "Afternoon", "Magic Hour", "Sundown", "Night", "Twilight", "Aurora", "Late Night", "Noon", "Noon", "Noon", "Noon", "Noon", "Noon", "Noon");
                var random  = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

                document.getElementById("zemo").innerHTML = random;
            }
        </script>
        <div>
            <script>
                function Landscape () {
                    var myArray = new Array("Canyon", "Grand Canyon", "Beach", "Cliff", "Mountain Range");
                    var random  = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

                    document.getElementById("kemo").innerHTML = random;
                }
            </script>
            <div>
                <script>
                    function Manmade () {
                        var myArray = new Array("Cityscape", "Futuristic Cityscape", "Futuristic City", "Futuristic Cityscape");
                        var random  = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

                        document.getElementById("uemo").innerHTML = random;
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is all the Electron Related Code:**

**Index.js**

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron

app.on('ready', function() {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/Test.html')
})
```

**Package.js**

```
{
  "name": "Drawing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"electron ."

  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: `id` should be unique in your entire document. You are using same `id`s for all the inputs.

Comment: could you elaborate, are you talking my paragraph Id's or something else.

Comment: i tried what you suggested and switching them all to classes, but then it messes up everything and I don't know what would be needed to inputed in the getElementbyID.

Comment: Welcome to **stackoverflow**, in addition to changing the ids to be unique, as correctly suggested, I would recommend start accepting answers to your questions, I've reviewed answer to your previous questions and two of them answers your issues. A best practice is accepting them, rewarding the community and making sure the community answers you in the future. In addition, relating to this specific question, what does it mean _"messes up everything"_? I think it is better you'll create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code, so we can investigate easily. Good luck.

Comment: Did you mean to write `package.json` instead of `Package.js`?